# How to set limit offset in Linux ls. I can limit list 10 files using ls -l head -10. But I need to get next set of results

Tags: linux, unix, ls

How to set limit offset in Linux ls command. I can limit listing 10 files using *ls -l head -10*. But How do I get next set of results. Is there any way?

Comment: `.. head -20 | tail -10`. Anyway this is off topic for SO. Voting to close.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Thrustmaster.. Got expected result.